# How can I authenticate user login info in xamarin that is stored in wamp server

Tags: c#, php, android, web-services, xamarin

Here is what I done so far:

This is my MainActivity.cs:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views.InputMethods;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;

namespace App
{
    [Activity(Label = "App", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {

            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            Button Login = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.button1);
            Login.Click += Login_Click;

        }

        private void Login_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            EditText username = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.editText1);
            EditText password = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.editText2);
            Login(username.Text, password.Text);

            //Intent Poziv = new Intent(this, typeof(AFLogcs));
            //this.StartActivity(Poziv);
            //this.Finish();
        }

        private void Login(string username, string password)
        {

        }

        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
            EditText username = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.editText1);
            EditText password = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.editText2);
            //Cisti fokus
            username.ClearFocus();
            password.ClearFocus();
            imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(username.WindowToken, 0);
            return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
        }

    }
}
```

I also created three php files in my c:/wamp64/www/android folder for connecting to database that is on wamp server.

here are the files:

Conn.php

```
<?php
$db_name = "korisnici";
$mysql_username = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$server_name = "localhost";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password,$db_name);
if($conn){
echo "Connection sucessfull";
}
else{
echo "No connection";
}
?>
```

And Login.php

```
<?php
require "Conn.php";
$user_name = "Mpro";
$user_pass = "nice";
$mysql_qry = "SELECT* FROM korisnici WHERE korisnik LIKE '$user_name' and sifra LIKE '$user_pass'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
echo "Uspjesan login";
}
else{
echo "login not success";
}
```

Now my problem is how can I pass data from android editTexts for username and password and authenticate to see if the user exist. And if user exists new activity will be pulled up and it would display user information from another table for that particular user.

Also once that data is acquired the user would be able to login to his app offline and still see the memorized data, but after connection to wifi again the app will automatically check if there was an update and if it was the app will pull it from the Wamp and again store it.

You don't have to share the code for data memorizing but please do for user login. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I also did login system using Web service. I used Xamarin android (`MvvmCross`), which used `ViewModel` and `Node JS` Web Service. Therefore, apology I could not help you much with the code to pass to another activity and the login in `php`.

However, I am able to share how I did it. First, I used `WebRequest` class to pass the username and password to the web service. You should check that out. The web service then will reply whether the login credential is right or wrong, the android application can use `StreamReader` to read the response. You could check the documentation of `WebRequest` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.createhttp(v=vs.110).aspx).

To save the login for offline purpose, what I suggest you to use is `ISharedPreferences` class. It will save the data in the persistent storage. The data that can be saved there is primitive data, such as `int`, `boolean`, `string`, `float`, and `stringset`. Using that, you could store `boolean` to check if the user has logged in (which you need to remove later on once the user logged out), the username and other data you need. Check it out in [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4758/android-shared-preference)

Hope this could help. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you Darren I will try my best.